# Error when deploying ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor web app to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just started using ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Razor view engine. It works great locally, however when I published the site to my web server, it gives me the error:

**Method not found: 'System.Web.Razor.GeneratorResults System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(System.IO.TextReader, System.String, System.String, System.String)'.**

I installed ASP.NET MVC 3 on the server and it's running under the .NET 4 app pool. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you have a preview version of MVC isntalled on the server. Make sure that you have MVC 3 RTM installed.

Comment: I installed it on the server today from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3, which is the same place I installed it from locally.

Comment: I went ahead and uninstalled it then reinstalled and then it worked, must've been something funky that happened in the first install.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you had an old version installed :) Perhaps you installed RTM over an earlier preview version and something didn't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstalling and reinstalling MVC alone didn't fix it, I needed to recycle my app pool and restart my IIS application as well.

My guess is there is a bug in the update from RC to RTM versions... [The Gu is on the case](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx#7694515) so i'm sure it will be fixed in the next MVC revision.